# Laravel 5 Eloquent getting records from related tables

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm new to laravel and I'm using Laravel 5.2 I want to have the record of the maximum end date in a bookings columns of a perticular request. My tables are like :

```
request
-----------
id | name
----------
1   | My request

bookings
-----------
id | request_id | start_date | end_date
--------------------------------------------
1   | 1         | 2016-03-01 | 2016-03-05
2   | 1         | 2016-03-10 | 2016-03-20
3   | 1         | 2016-03-25 | 2016-03-28

Request Model
------------------
public function bookings()
{
    return $this->hasMany( 'App\Booking' );
}
```

I want to have the request data with the maximum end date ( for the example above the record will be booking Id : 3 ). Please help.

I've tried the following :

```
$request = \DB::table( 'requests' )
                ->join( 'bookings', 'requests.id', '=', 'bookings.request_id' )
                ->where( 'requests.id', 1 )
                ->max( 'bookings.end_date' );
```

But I wonder how to do this with eloquent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can desc-order by that date and pick the first record:

`$request = Request::find(1)->bookings()->orderBy('end_date', 'DESC')->first();`

Comment: The bookings in the table can be in any order. For example :

`1   | 1         | 2016-03-01 | 2016-03-05
2   | 1         | 2016-03-25 | 2016-03-25
3   | 1         | 2016-03-10 | 2016-03-20`

Comment: @Pranab I don't understand the problem, if you set an `ORDER BY end_date` clause they will be __ordered__ regardless of their entry order. Does the above function work for you or not?

Comment: Ahh....yes it is working. Sorry I didn't get your answer on the first sight but is it clear now. Thank you :)